# Perl: Как добавлять в файл не дубли

Tags: perl

подскажите пожалуйста как правильно написать, что бы в файл выводились только уникальные значения, а дубли не добавлялись.
Я только несколько дней разбираюсь в Perle, ниже мой код, вернее не мой, а попытка переделать чужое под свои потребности. С помощью этого кода, я получаю имена при каждом запуске приложения, но они дублируются и я не понимаю, как сделать так, что бы запись добавлялась только 1 раз.
Вот код:

```
package playerRecord;

use strict;
use Plugins;
use Log qw(message);
use Globals;
use Settings;
use Actor;
use Utils qw(binAdd existsInList getFormattedDate);
use utf8;
use warnings 'all';
use List::MoreUtils;
use List::MoreUtils qw( uniq );

Plugins::register("prec1", "playerRecord1", \&on_unload, \&on_reload);
my $hook = Plugins::addHook('charNameUpdate', \&write_player, undef);

sub on_unload {
    Plugins::delHook("charNameUpdate", $hook);
}
sub on_reload {
    message "playerRecord1 plugin reloading, ";
    Plugins::delHook("charNameUpdate", $hook);
}
sub write_player {
    my (undef, $args) = @_;
    my $self = shift;
    my $selfName = $char->name();
    my $file = "./MyID.txt";
    message "MyID IS: $selfName\n";
    
    
    open FILE, ">>:utf8", $file;
    print FILE "$selfName \n";
    close FILE;
}

1;
```

Спасибо.

Comment: в коде запись одного игрока. Где здесь чтение, я не вижу.

Comment: Простите, но мне не много не понятен вопрос. Смотрите, данный код получает имя игрока и помещает его в файл, и делает это раз за разом. Мне нужно сделать проверку на существование такого имени и если оно есть, то не добавлять его.
Из гугла пробовал разные примеры, но когда пробую  вставить в скрипт, то все равно идет вставка дублей

Comment: Я бы создал хэш и добавлял туда записи вида "имя: +". Если $хэш{имя} равно '+', тогда такое имя уже есть, и не надо делать ничего; если undef, тогда имя ещё не существует. Конечно, хэш надо будет заполнять из файла при старте программы.

Comment: Я пробовал примеры с хешами, но скорее всего из-за не знания языка, либо из-за кривого применения, я получаю опять дубли. Сейчас попробовал засунуть все в массив и его через uniq фильтровать, но получаю вообще отсутствие записей. Как правильно это написать?

Comment: надо смотреть на весь код, где то должен быть код, который их загружает. Ну или при сохранении вначале считать, потом проверить на дубликат и потом, по надобности записать

Comment: Если этот скрипт не работает постоянно, а периодически запускается для записи одного имени, то простой хеш не поможет. Вам надо сначала прочитать MyID.txt и создать реестр имен в хеше.

Comment: не благодарите) https://i.imgur.com/5UjgXsW.png обратите внимание, у меня переменная $selfName без пробелов, и $found туда случайно попала)

Comment: @usr13 спасибо огромное!!!! Работает как я хотел!